# Show UISearchController in a modal VC already in focus

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I want to achieve the following:

- The user wants to link with a company using a button
- A modal VC with a search field is animated in (from the bottom up)
- The search field should already have focus (off-screen)

I got this only partially working, which seems weird for such a simple scenario.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Problems:

1. I *had* to put the `becomeFirstResponder()` code in view**Did**Appear since view**Will**Appear did not work at all and the focus would not be on the search field.

   So there is one additional animation with the **Cancel** button animating in, which I think is not required.
2. I had to use a somewhat nasty `dispatch_async` call, otherwise the focus of the search text field would not work too.

I now wonder, how to do this properly so that the text field gets focus off-screen.

#### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Why `dispatch_async` and not `dispatch_after` ?

Comment: @Teo. The search field did not get the focus so I tried out dispatch_async and it worked. But generally I don't want to delay this process...

Comment: Do you need to show some pre-populated data? If you require a search functionality like in the weather app (i.e. results are displayed only after search then I know how to solve your problem)

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk No, I don't need pre-populated data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since you do not require pre-populated data (and therefore you do not require 2 table views) here is a trick which worked for me.

Instead of using `UISearchController` you can use search bar directly.

1) First create a new subclass of `UISearchBar` to ensure that it does not have a Cancel button

```
class SearchBarWithoutCancelButton:UISearchBar {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: false)
    }
}
```

2) In your view controller add the following declarations/function:

```
    lazy var searchBar:SearchBarWithoutCancelButton = {
        let bar = SearchBarWithoutCancelButton()
        bar.delegate = self
        bar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
        bar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationItem.titleView = bar
        return bar
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = [.Left,.Right,.Bottom]
        self.navigationItem.prompt = "Enter town, city, postcode, or airport location"
        self.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        //here you should call the function which will update your data source and reload table view (or other UI that you have)
        self.performSearch()
    }

    @IBAction func dismiss() {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Then in your storyboard add the right bar button item with Cancel title (can use default system item) and connect its selector to the `dismiss()` function defined above. This needs to be done because if you use the Cancel button of the search bar you will get an unwanted animation when search bar resigns first responder.

This code does make search bar in focus when view appears and keyboard slides as part of the animation.

When you press Cancel button view dismisses nicely as well. In my case, when user taps on search results, I want to add that item and then dismiss the view. If that is what you need as well then call `dismiss()` at that point as well. If you want to allow more than one search result addition, check to make sure that search bar remains active after user presses on the search result (if that is what you need).

As to the data source it is very simple - just create an empty array for search results and make sure that the number of sections/rows in your table view corresponds to the number of items in that array. When user taps on Search just update it and call `self.tableView.reloadData()`.

Let me know if this works for you